# Increase speed of changing Excell cell's value with just a mouse

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to increase the speed of changing Excel cell's value with a mouse only. I share my tool in hope that someone will like it and want to improve it.

This is an example. After clicking on a defined cell containing value, scrollbar appears on the right side of a cell. You can smoothly change its value with a mouse.

[image]

The tool is meant to change cells value and observe formulas values dynamically. You may simplify the code however some features should not be disabled. It should always stay dynamic, that is moving the srollbar should immediately influence other cells with formulas. The srollbar should not twinkle (changing colour grey and black).

You may simply [download the *scrollbar.xlsm* file here](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B3TGVycQLkZ_RDVjMXUyanZVQm8&export=download) and view the VBA code inside it.

Or you may put this code in your sheet where you want the scollbars to appear. The name of your sheet does not matter. Right click on the sheet's name and then click `View Code`. This is the place:

[image]

Insert there this code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim previousRow, c
Const scrlName As String = "scrlSh" ' the name of the scrollbar


Private Sub scrlSh_GotFocus()
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(scrlName).TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1).Address).Activate
End Sub

Private Sub scrlSh_Scroll()
Dim rngCell As Range

Set rngCell = Sheets("Param").Range(ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(scrlName).LinkedCell)

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(scrlName).TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = _
        rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value + (ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(scrlName).Object.Value * rngCell.Offset(0, 3).Value)

Set rngCell = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
' Macro concept by Przemyslaw Remin, VBA code written by Jaroslaw Smolinski
' The Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange and function SearchAdr have to be on each sheet where scrollbars are to appear
' Sheet Param is one for all sheets, only the columns A-G are used, othre columns can be used for something else
' Do not change the layout of A-G columns unless you want to modify the code
' Addresses in Param have to be with dollars (i.e. $A$3) or it may be named ranges of single cells
' (if it starts with $ it is a cell, otherwise it is a named range)
' the lower or upper case in addresses does not matter


Dim SheetFly As String, adr As String
Dim cCell As Range
Dim actSheet As Worksheet
Dim shScroll As Object

    Set actSheet = ActiveSheet

    ' checks if scrollbar exists
    If actSheet.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
        For Each shScroll In actSheet.Shapes
            If shScroll.Type = msoOLEControlObject And shScroll.Name = scrlName Then
                Exit For ' scrollbar found, and the variable is set
            End If
        Next shScroll
    End If
    ' if scrollbar does not exists then it is created
    If shScroll Is Nothing Then
        Set shScroll = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ScrollBar.1", Link:=False, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=64 * 3, Height:=15)
            ' scrollbar length is set as three adjesent columns
        shScroll.Visible = False
        shScroll.Name = scrlName
        shScroll.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    End If

    shScroll.Visible = False
    adr = Target.AddressLocal
    SheetFly = actSheet.Name


    ' here we set up in which cells the scrollbar has to appear. We set up only the number of rows
    Set cCell = SearchAdr(SheetFly, adr, Sheets("Param").Range("B2:B40")) ' If needed it can be longer i.e. B2:B400
    If Not cCell Is Nothing Then
        With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(scrlName)
            .LinkedCell = "" ' temporary turn off of the link to the cell to avoid stange behaviour
            .Object.Min = 0 ' the scale begins from 0, not negative
            .Object.Max = Abs((cCell.Offset(0, 4).Value - cCell.Offset(0, 3).Value) / cCell.Offset(0, 5).Value)
            .Object.SmallChange = 10   ' single change by one step
            .Object.LargeChange = 10   ' change by jumps after clicking on scrollbar bar ("page up", "page down")
            If Target.Value <> cCell.Offset(0, 2).Value And Target.Value >= cCell.Offset(0, 3).Value And Target.Value <= cCell.Offset(0, 4).Value Then
                ' setting up the cells value as close as possible to the value of input by hand
                ' rounded by step
                ' if value is out of defined range then the last value will be used
                cCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Abs((Target.Value - cCell.Offset(0, 3).Value) / cCell.Offset(0, 5).Value)
            End If
            'Protection in case the value is out of min and max range
            If cCell.Offset(0, 2).Value > .Object.Max Then
                cCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = .Object.Max
            ElseIf cCell.Offset(0, 2).Value < .Object.Min Then
                cCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = .Object.Min
            End If
            Target.Value = cCell.Offset(0, 3).Value + (cCell.Offset(0, 5).Value * cCell.Offset(0, 2).Value)
            .Object.Value = cCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            .LinkedCell = "Param!" & cCell.Offset(0, 2).Address 'setting up linked cell
        End With
        ' Setting up the position and width of scrollbar with reference to the cell
        shScroll.Top = Target.Top
        shScroll.Left = Target.Offset(0, 1).Left + 2 'position to the right + small margin
        shScroll.Width = Target.Offset(0, 5).Left - Target.Offset(0, 1).Left - 2 'width of 5 columns
        shScroll.Visible = True
    End If

    Set actSheet = Nothing
    Set shScroll = Nothing
    Set cCell = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function SearchAdr(SheetFly As String, SearchCell As String, rng As Range) As Range
Dim cCell As Range
Dim oOOo As Name

' Searching for the row with parameter for chosen cell
' The parameter have to be in one, continouse range

For Each cCell In rng
    If cCell.Text = "" Then ' check if parameters have not finished
        Set SearchAdr = Nothing
        Exit Function ' stop if you find first empty cell for speeding
    ElseIf Left(cCell.Text, 1) = "$" Then ' normal address
        If cCell.Offset(0, 1).Text & "!" & UCase(cCell.Text) = SheetFly & "!" & UCase(SearchCell) Then
            Set SearchAdr = cCell
            Exit Function   ' exit if find proper row with parameters
        End If
    Else ' means that found is a name
        For Each oOOo In ActiveWorkbook.Names
            If (oOOo.RefersTo = "=" & SheetFly & "!" & UCase(SearchCell)) And (UCase(oOOo.Name) = UCase(cCell.Text)) Then
                Set SearchAdr = cCell
                Exit Function   ' exit if find proper row with parameters
            End If
        Next oOOo
    End If
Next cCell

End Function
```

In your workbook you have to make sheet named `Param` where the parameters of scrollbar are stored. In column A and C put the name of your sheet where you want scrollbars to appear. The sheet looks like this:

[image]

Now you can enjoy the scrollbar after clicking the cell in the `model` sheet.

Note that you can define different min, max ranges and step of scrollbar change separately for every cell. Moreover, the min and max range can be negative.

Comment: Przemyslaw, you may want to "ask" your "question" / share on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) rather than SO.

Comment: I get error ```Method 'LinkedCell' of object '_OLEObject' failed```. At line ```.LinkedCell = "" ' temporary turn off of the link to the cell to avoid stange behaviour```. Tested with Excel 2007. Maybe you could speed up the function ```SearchAdr```. Instead of looping through a ```Range``` get values into variant array and loop through the array elements. That is faster.

Comment: @dee Have you tested the file from download or the code posted below the download link? I have just tested the downloaded file on Excel 2003 and Excel 2010 and it works fine.

Comment: Well I have tested the downloaded file again with Excel 2007 but on different computer and it works fine. So the problem is probably not in the file itself, but on my home computer.

Comment: downloded and unlocked file, doesn't work in excel 2010 , no errors, no scroll bars..

Comment: @StevenMartin It works well on Excel 2013, 2010, 2007, 2003. Just check out your macro security settings. If you have xlsm file with working macros just copy my code inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

 If OLEObjects.Count = 0 Then OLEObjects.Add "Forms.ScrollBar.1", , , , , , , Target.Offset(, 1).Left, Target.Top, 199, 15

 With OLEObjects(1)
   .Top = Target.Top
   .object.max=200
   Target = Application.Max(Target, .Object.Min)
   Target = Application.Min(Target, .Object.Max)
   .LinkedCell = Target.Address
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which part of my code should it replace? Can you explain the 3rd line of your code? What does 199 and 15 at the end stand for?

Comment: It should replace all your code. You can check in the helpfiles of the VBEditor, what 192 (3*64) width and 15 (height) stand for.

Comment: You have defined max as 32767 (where in your code?). The scrollbar flickers (and it should not). Scrollbar does not disappear if you select other cell i.e. `B2`. PS Incredible, I am surprised by the shortness of your code. Bravo!

Comment: I added .object.max=200 to illustrate how you can easily adapt the properties (also the .object.min, etc.) of the scrollbar.

Comment: (1) What about the flickering of the bar grey-black? Can we avoid it in your solution? (In my solution it does not flicker). (2) How to disable the scrollbar after selecting B1 cell?

Comment: I would remove the line `Target = Application.Max(Target, .Object.Min)` and its twin below.

Answer (score 1):

To make the value change when clicking on left/right arrow or inside the scrollbar, I'd rather add:

```
Private Sub scrlSh_Change()
If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(scrlName).LinkedCell <> "" Then
    scrlSh_Scroll
End If
End Sub
```

I'd prefer use typed function like `UCase$`, `Left$`, ... rather than their variant equivalent (`UCase`, `Left`, ...), but for this macro the "true" performance is not really required.

Within your Worksheet_SelectionChange sub, I've replaced the `actSheet`, `SheetFly` and `adr` variables by their original values (as there are used only once). No real big improvment yet.